# Strange ColdFusion path issue (ExpandPath resultant)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Hoping someone on here knows ColdFusion, and further, may know what is going on.

```
<cfscript>
    sz_test1=ExpandPath("/app/folder/afternoon.jpg");
    sz_test2=ExpandPath("app/folder/afternoon.jpg");

    WriteOutput(sz_test1&"<br />");
    WriteOutput(sz_test2&"<br />");
    abort;
</cfscript>
```

Simple code, simply outputting [ExpandPath](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/expandpath.html)() results.

### Situation:

Website running ColdFusion 11 prints out an image to a page based on time of day. 
Simple page, if it's in afternoon, you get afternoon.jpg, otherwise morning.jpg.
ExpandPath is required since we actually output the page contents to a pdf (cfdocument + cfimage), which isn't important for purpose of this question. But letting you know so no one suggests not using ExpandPath as a resolution..

### Problem

Somehow on this page, just 5 minutes ago, the resultant for variable **sz_test1** would come back with the ColdFusion path. Not the web root path.

```
C:\Coldfusion11\CFIDE\app\folder\afternoon.jpg
```

whereas **sz_test2** would give:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\folder\afternoon.jpg
```

So naturally the file doesn't exist in the first case.
But now, suddenly, ColdFusion is no longer doing that. Both tests return the exact same result. This has been consistently happening (consistently inconsistent results) for a few weeks.

### Question:

Anyone know what would cause the ExpandPath() function to:

1. Return inconsistent results when prefixed with a slash
2. Return different results suddenly without any change to the code (or environment) whatsoever.

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2519-expandpath-works-with-coldfusion-s-per-application-mappings.htm
looks like the [ / ]  prefix is known to cause unexpected results. But the real issue is that the servlet context is somehow mapping the wrong application mapped path. I don't know how that is possible.

Comment: might this be something corrected in a more recent CF11 update?

Comment: Check to see if you have "/app" defined as a mapping in CF admin or Application.cfc.

Comment: I do have the latest Coldfusion update applied, and also 100% I do have that /app defined in application.cfc mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using
 thisPath=getDirectoryFromPath (getCurrentTemplatePath);
 thisFile="#thisPath#/folder/afternoon.jpg";

It's a little bulky but might get rid of the inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Excellent, will give this a shot and report back, thank you!

Comment: Works great, this is a valid alternative to ExpandPath() that is reliable. I'm still unsure how ExpandPath() is failing but it seems to be due to the application.cfc mappings, and perhaps originates due to locking(cflock) for threaded operations. I believe, that when the lock takes place, the application scope becomes inaccessible due to the lock, causing existing sessions which try to utilize it the inability to recover application scope mappings. It's very strange, just posting what my running theory on this is. But it definitely has to do with application path mappings and scope.

Comment: Do you have an explicit cflock in your application.cfc when you set the mappings? If so, you could try setting the mapping in cfadministrator. You could also try changing the lock to read only (as opposed to read/write).